# Some Files unreadable

Tags: 18.10

When checking "Properties" on "Home" folder I get a message:
"some files unreadable"
Why? and How do I find them to correct or delete?

Answer (score 0):

In each file system there is a folder lost+found which is normally empty and which has the permissions

```
~$ ls -l /home
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 54 jean jean  4096 Mär  9 08:41 jean
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Mär  4 20:38 lost+found
```

So this would be at least one file not readable by you. There may be many others of course. You can find them using the command

```
find /home ! -readable
```